# Increasing font size for html email on mobile

Tags: html, email, fonts, html-email

I have problem with increasing font size on email for mobile apps. I am using Ink foundation framework. I have added to my custom styles:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){                    
        .p {font-size:16px!important; line-height:20px;}        
}
```

But on mobile (iOs Mail) this rule is completely ignored and font size is tiny so probably the default desktop font is applied (which is 13px). Other media queries are working.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of possibilities that could cause issues.

iOS will adjust font sizes automatically. To prevent this, you can apply:

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Without seeing your html, it is tough to tell, but you might be trying to target the `p` tag in which case you do not need a period in front of the selector (like a class), so you would change it to:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    p {
        font-size: 16px!important;
        line-height:20px;
    }
}
```